# How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time

Tags: macros, foreach

I would like to keep track of all the `\AddRef` commands in a document and then process them one at a time, for instance print them in the document on one line per value.  It seems that this should be doable as the functionality is not that different than list of figures that, but I can' seem to get this to work.  I did not even attempt the `\foreach` command required at the end of the file so if someone knows how to do that that would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\newtoks{\Ref}
\newcommand{\AddRef}[1]{%
    \let\OldRef=\the\Ref\relax
    \let\Ref=\the\OldRef{#1}\relax
}

\AddRef{Ref 1}
\AddRef{Ref 2}
\AddRef{Ref 3}

The list of Ref are:
\the\Ref

\end{document}
```

At the end, I would like to process the list, say to print a line at a time:

Ref 1

Ref 2

Ref 3

---

The original question above required the case where this list of strings is a global macro so that it is complete at the end of the document.  Another application requires that this list of strings be local to a scope so a local version would also be useful.

Comment: Related Question: [Long List of Files Names with Paths](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174885/long-list-of-files-names-with-paths).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand\AddRefList{}
\newcommand\AddRef[1]{\edef\AddRefList{\AddRefList#1\endgraf}}
\begin{document}

\AddRef{Ref 1}
\AddRef{Ref 2}
\AddRef{Ref 3}

The list of Ref are:

\AddRefList

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the `\edef` be an `\xdef` as then it works independent of where `\AddRef` is called from.

Comment: one important rule: use global definitions only when they are really needed ...

Comment: Ok, point taken. Was using this in a possible solution to [Print macro output instead of executing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73720/print-macro-output-instead-of-executing) and took me some time to figure out what was going on...

Answer (score 13):

The `\let\OldRef=\the\Ref` doesn't work because `\OldRef` is then simply a copy of `\the`. Also note that `\Ref` here stands for `\toks<number>` and coping it using `\let` would only let both macros point to the same token register.

You can accumulate code using the `\g@addto@macro` macro:

```
\def\Ref{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AddRef}[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\Ref{{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

This redefines a macro, which is less efficient than using a token register, but this should be OK in your case.

Instead of using a *for* loop I would simply add the required macros as part of the definition of `\Ref`, so that you simply have to use the macro. The ToC and List of Figures is generated by writing such code into an external file instead.

Comment: Both of these work. But in which circumstances is one better than the other? I am not too concerned about speed.

Comment: And the reason I wanted to use a for loop at the end, is that I have not yet figured out exactly how I am going to do the processing that is needed, so had planned on temporarily outputing a `\todo` statement for now and coming back later to fix it. That way I did not need to change the collection of these, just the processing of the `\Ref`(s). I could of course collect the `\todo` as part of the list as it is created, and then later change this, but that solution somehow seems wrong.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a local version of `\g@addto@macro` without using up a new token register you could use something like

```
\long\def\@addto@macro#1#2{%
\begingroup
\toks@\expandafter{#1#2}%
\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter
\edef\expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\toks@}%
}
```

this uses the scratch register `\toks@` without affecting its existing contents, it is basically `\g@addto@macro` but using `\edef` rather than `\xdef` and with a few extra `\expandafter` to compensate.

Comment: On the other hand, this particular application seems to require global definitions, since `\AddRef` might be used inside an environment.

Comment: @egreg I was asked by the OP in chat for a local version of g@addto@macro and I always do what I'm told:-)