# Expansion issue: How Check if options passed to an environment were used

Tags: expansion

I have an environment with portions of the content that being conditionally typeset based on options passed to the environment. The content of this environment is predefined elsewhere so depending on the options different output is produced. This portion of the code works fine.

Now I am trying to report an error at the end of the environment if an unrecognized option was specified to detect any typos that might go unnoticed, and have run into what seems like an expansion issue.  I tried all the possible uses of `\edef` and `\expandafter`s that remotely made sense to me but have not found the right combination.

I do this be storing a list of all the options that were specified, and at the end I check that control sequence `\<optionName>Encountered` was defined for each of the specified options.  In the body of the environment, I define:

```
\global\expandafter\def\csname <optionName> Encountered\endcsname{}%
```

for every possible `<optionName>` that could have been specified, and check against the list of options that were specified.

### Note:

- There are other options in the list of options to which this sort of checking is not to be applied, so I do need to individually add them to the list as opposed to just storing `#1` and doing the `\foreach` loop at the end over that value.
- I would prefer that the options themselves be stored in the list (not their corresponding csname), as then I can better report the error message at the end of the environment.
- Also, the options may also be defined in a macro.

### References:

- [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time)

### Expected Output:

When the code in `\ReportAnyUnusedOptions` is uncommented and things are working, this should produce:

[image]

### Code:

The problem code in `\ReportAnyUnusedOptions` has been commented to allow this to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\ListOfOptions{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AddToListOfOptions}[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\ListOfOptions{#1}%
    \typeout{***** Added option to check: #1}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\ReportAnyUnusedOptions}{%
    Checking options: \par%
        \foreach \y in \ListOfOptions {%
%           \y%
%           \ifcsname\y Encountered\endcsname%
%               ~Encountered!\par%
%           \else%
%               ~Not Encountered!\par%
%           \fi%
        }%
}%

\newenvironment{ApplyOptions}[1]{%
   % Add to list of options to later check that they were used
    \foreach \x in {#1} {%
        % There are cases here where an option would not be
        % check later, so some will be skipped
        \edef\Option{\x}%
        \AddToListOfOptions{\Option}%
    }%
}{%
    \ReportAnyUnusedOptions%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{ApplyOptions}{Option A, Option C}%
    % Option A:
    % if "Option A" was specified, it would be typset here
    \global\expandafter\def\csname Option A Encountered\endcsname{}%
    %
    % Option B:
    % if "Option B" was specified, it would be typset here
    \global\expandafter\def\csname Option B Encountered\endcsname{}%
\end{ApplyOptions}

% Also possible to specify the options via a macro
\newcommand*{\MyOptions}{Option AA, Option CC}%
\begin{ApplyOptions}{\MyOptions}%
    % Option A:
    % if "Option AA" was specified, it would be typset here
    \global\expandafter\def\csname Option AA Encountered\endcsname{}%
    %
    % Option B:
    % if "Option BB" was specified, it would be typset here
    \global\expandafter\def\csname Option BB Encountered\endcsname{}%
\end{ApplyOptions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but isn't this what some `*keyval*` packages solve?

Comment: @tohecz: When I saw you comment this morning, I thought "Wow, that sure makes sense". But not that I think about it more it is not a direct solution, but one could probably adapt a keyval package to do this. In my case, the option names are not limited to a certain list, so the key values would need to be built on the fly.

Comment: Well, I thought that this is the isuue, but maybe dynamical (regex-defined?) keys are the next thing needed in `keyval` packages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an `expl3` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_optchk_options_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \optchk_report: 
 {
  Checking~options: \par
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_optchk_options_seq
   {
    ##1 ~ \cs_if_exist:cF { ##1 ~ Encountered } {~ Not} ~ Encountered \par
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \optchk_add:n #1
 {
  \seq_gclear:N \g_optchk_options_seq
  % Add to list of options to later check that they were used
  \seq_gset_split:Nno \g_optchk_options_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_optchk_options_seq
   { \typeout{*****~Added~option~to~check:~##1} }
 }
 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_split:Nnn {Nno}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ApplyOptions}{ m }
 { \optchk_add:n { #1 } }
 { \optchk_report: }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{ApplyOptions}{Option A, Option C}%
    % Option A:
    % if "Option A" was specified, it would be typset here
    \expandafter\gdef\csname Option A Encountered\endcsname{}%
    %
    % Option B:
    % if "Option B" was specified, it would be typset here
    \expandafter\gdef\csname Option B Encountered\endcsname{}%
\end{ApplyOptions}
\end{document}
```

A limit of the `\foreach` approach is, as usual, the fact that all cycles are executed in a different group. The approach with sequences (or clists) allows for choosing global assignments when needed and makes management easier.

Here we define the environment to add the specified options to the sequence (and we have no delimiting problem). The "end part" of the environment does your `\ReportAnyUnusedOptions` under a different name.

Note: I've changed `\seq_gset_split:Nnn` into `\seq_gset_split:Nno` so that the argument passed to the environment is expanded once. Depending on the nature of the options one might prefer to use `\seq_gset_split:Nnx` (generating the appropriate variant) but this might be dangerous if the options contain themselves macros.

Comment: I am not able to get this to work in the case where the options are defined via a macro.

Comment: @PeterGrill Edited to cope with this case.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Your list of options was not holding what you thought. After two options it was defined as

```
\ListOfOptions=macro:
->\Option \Option .
```

ie it only told you the number of options not which ones.

so change so it holds

```
> \ListOfOptions=macro:
->\Option A Encountered \Option C Encountered .
```

Then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\ListOfOptions{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AddToListOfOptions}[1]{%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\ListOfOptions \csname #1 Encountered\endcsname
    \typeout{***** Added option to check: #1}%
}


\def\foo#1>{}

\newcommand{\ReportAnyUnusedOptions}{%
    Checking options: \par%
    \def\x{\@tfor\y:=}%
       \expandafter\x\ListOfOptions\do{%
           \expandafter\show\y\relax
           \expandafter\ifx\y\@undefined
            \expandafter\foo\meaning\y!\par%
           \else%
            NOT \expandafter\foo\meaning\y!\par%
           \fi}%
}%

\newenvironment{ApplyOptions}[1]{%
   % Add to list of options to later check that they were used
    \foreach \x in {#1} {%
        % There are cases here where an option would not be
        % check later, so some will be skipped
        \edef\Option{\x}%
        \AddToListOfOptions{\Option}%
    }%
}{%
    \ReportAnyUnusedOptions%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{ApplyOptions}{Option A, Option C}%
    % Option A:
    % if "Option A" was specified, it would be typset here
    \global\expandafter\def\csname Option A Encountered\endcsname{}%
    %
    % Option B:
    % if "Option B" was specified, it would be typset here
    \global\expandafter\def\csname Option B Encountered\endcsname{}%
\end{ApplyOptions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just used `\@tfor` rather than the pgf foreach thing as I know what it does:-)

Comment: The OP should be using LaTeX’s `\@for` instead of `\foreach`. When the list has only one holder macro (`\x` above) and no ellipsis (`...`), then `\foreach` is a waste of resources: its use then doesn't justify the cost. It was designed for the giant PGF/TikZ, were speed isn't a curable goal. Also, it gives scoped results. It doesn't normalize lists. Hence leading and trailing spaces around 'Options' can give the OP surprising results.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ummm... I think you have the logic backwards. The **NOT** should be when the expected csname is `@undefined`..

Comment: Oh perhaps:-) fortunately having logic backwards gives an isomorphic structure, so it's just as good as the original one. It may model the real world less well, but that's a minor issue for a pure mathematician.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am not able to get this to work for the case where the options are specified via a macro (see updated MWE). Also, would really prefer to store the option name to make the error message at the end more meaningful..

Comment: When was David Carlisle last a pure mathematician? 1990?

Comment: @AhmedMusa 1997 was last time I had a university position in pure maths, but being a mathematician is a state of mind, not a job title:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That was just a joke. I read a statement by you somewhere, in which you said you had learnt hard math, only to end up displaying math.

Comment: @AhmedMusa  yes, I know:) but since it's against the house style to leave questions unanswered, that was in fact an honest answer to your question:-)

Answer (score 1):

I want to save Peter one full loop per environment call. That is why I posted this solution. Also, `\cptdocommalist` normalizes the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\optionsnotused}{%
  Checking options:
  \def\do##1##2{\endgraf{\tt % You can remove \tt if you like.
    \ifdefTF{##2}{%
      Option `##1' used: \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning##2%
      \undefcs{##2}% remove any \gdef'ed temporary commands.
    }{%
      Option `##1' not used%
    }%
  }}%
  \listofoptions
}
\newenvironment{applyoptions}[1]{%
  % \listofoptions is re-initialized by the environment. I am not sure 
  % if this is what Peter intended. If not, take '\def\listofoptions{}'
  % outside the environment definition:
  \def\listofoptions{}%
  \ifmacroTF{#1}{\let\cpt@tempa#1}{\def\cpt@tempa{#1}}%
  \cptdocommalist*\cpt@tempa{%
    \edef\option{##1}% Does Peter really need to define \option here?
    \xdef\listofoptions{\expandcsonce\listofoptions
      \unexpanded{\do{##1}}{\noexpandcsn{##1-used}}}%
    \typeout{Option '\detokenize{##1}' added, to check at end of environment.}%
  }%
}{%
  \optionsnotused
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{applyoptions}{Option A, Option B}
  % If 'Option A' was specified, it would be typeset here.
  % Let us simulate its use here:
  \csngdef*{Option A-used}{Used here by Peter Gill}%
  % Let's assume that 'Option B' wasn't used here.
\end{applyoptions}
\end{document}
```