# Store and retrieve content across documents

Tags: input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Automating quoting across LaTeX documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57223/automating-quoting-across-latex-documents)

I'm working on 2 documents: `1.tex` and `2.tex`.

`2.tex` is a metadocument about `1.tex`, so that `2.tex` has a lot of quotations from `1.tex`. Thus, if I modify `1.tex`, I need to modify `2.tex` to reflect the changes accordingly. Such a procedure, however, is tedious and error-prone.

My question is: how can I store content from `1.tex` for later insertion in `2.tex`? I was wondering if there is any package like this:

`1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{foo}
\begin{document}
First sentence. \StoreAndPrint{<key>}{Second sentence}. Third sentence.
\end{document}
```

`2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{foo}
\begin{document}
The author says:
 \begin{quote}
 \RetrieveAndPrint{<key>}
 \end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Running `$ latex 1`, and then `$ latex 2`, would output an automatically updated `2.dvi`.

#### `\input`

I could create as many separate `tex` files as quotations, and then `\input` them into both documents, but that would make editing `1.tex` too hard.

Comment: Just to be clear: `1.tex` and `2.tex` will be used to produce two distinct documents?

Comment: @egreg: Yes. I edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: (1) is the quoted material in the same order in 2.tex as in 1.tex?  (2) is there additional material in 2.tex that isn't in 1.tex?  if the answer to (1) is yes, it might be possible to include everything in a single file, and by means of a switch, choose to output either 1.dvi or 2.dvi as appropriate.

Comment: @nicolai.rostov On that basis, I've closed as a dupe.

Comment: @nicolai.rostov I've just added to the other question the answer I was preparing for this one.