# Is \Copy already in use by any package?

Tags: emacs, package-writing, vim, copy-paste

I'm working on my `copypaste` package to address a confusing feature that [Seamus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57223/automating-quoting-across-latex-documents/91383#comment198127_91383) has kindly drawn my attention to.

`\yank` copies text and commands from a LaTeX document onto a "clipboard", and `\paste` pastes it into the same (or another) LaTeX document.

I called it "yank" because (i) `\copy` is already defined in TeX, and (ii) "yank" is how `vim` users refer to copy. However, "yank" seems to mean the **opposite** of copy in `emacs`. (I don't use `emacs`.) That's confusing.

My question is: is `\Copy` already in use by any other package? That is, would any package that you know of conflict with mine if I renamed `\yank` to `\Copy` (uppercase)? Any suggestion for a better name?

Comment: `\copy` is an important TeX primitive. I've never seen `\Copy`.

Comment: emacs -nw C-h k C-y returns: C-y runs the command yank
  which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.
It is bound to C-y, <S-insertchar>, <S-insert>, <menu-bar> <edit> <paste>.
(yank &optional ARG)

Reinsert ("paste") the last stretch of killed text.
More precisely, reinsert the stretch of killed text most recently

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\Copy` probably isn't used as a document level command but then that is because it's not a good name for a document level command (according to the somewhat under-enforced LaTeX command naming guidelines).

See [Macro naming best practice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48195/macro-naming-best-practice/48207#48207)

Other possibilities would be:

1. emacs naming (clearly good:-)

   `\kill` and `\yank`   (but some people may find that a bit aggressive terminology:-)
2. using a prefix (say cp)

   `\cpcopy` `\cppaste`
3. using an argument form

   `\cp{paste}` `\cp{yank}`

Not sure if any of those are suitable, hard to say without seeing the package, but possible ideas..