# How to use a string in an auxiliary file to update the header?

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing, content-replication

A document (typical of many) has a header which displays a timestamp in the form of a text string (“25 December 2013”).  The timestamp string originates in a file `"update"` which is loaded with `\input`.

I attempted to construct a minimal working example, but the example (three files) does not work as I expected it to work.

```
% this is a listing of example.cls
\ProvidesPackage{example}
\LoadClassWithOptions{book}
\newcommand{\timestamp}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\revision}{ \timestamp}
```

```
% this is a listing of example.tex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{example}
\begin{document}
This line represents the document header: \revision
\input{update} % update data from external file
Now the header should reflect the update: \revision
\end{document}
```

```
% this is a listing of "update"
% the date string should update the document header:
\timestamp{25 December 2013}
This line represents update text, which typically consists of dozens of lines.
```

After much searching and reading, I still do not understand which LaTeX mechanism – such as `\savebox` or `\renewcommand` – is appropriate for this task.  Also, I am confused regarding the proper location for the definitions of `\timestamp` and `\revision` – should they be defined in the class file (`example.cls`), in the main document file (`example.tex`), or in the file (`update`) which periodically updates the main document file?  My inclination is to define as much as possible in the class file, because there are over a thousand document files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 5):

I think this does what you want. You don't need a new `.cls` file.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\revision}{dummy value}

\newcommand{\timestamp}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\revision}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
This line represents the document header: \revision

\input{update} % update data from external file, type .tex

Now the header should reflect the update: \revision

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the revision line that appears in the document header before the input text needs the new value of the timestamp you'll have to work a little harder - see [how to make text be copied to another part of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150790/how-to-make-text-be-copied-to-another-part-of-a-document)

Comment: I thank you, kind sir.  The solution you gave appears to serve my need perfectly.

And I do have need for a customized .cls file, because the document is fairly complex, with several sections, a complex first-page header, and header and footer on all pages.  The class defines over a thousand similar but unique documents, and each document is likely to be updated a dozen or more times.

Needless to say, the alternative of manually modifying the header via cut-and-paste is daunting.

Comment: @user43157: If this solves your problem please consider marking the answer as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).