# Quoting from the same document?

Tags: copy-paste, quotation, clipboard

How to quote from the same document? For example

> SECTION 3. Explanation
>
> Before discussing the main theorem, let's quote it's statement.
>
> Theorem **7.1.** (Main lemma) 1 + 1 = 2
>
> ...
>
> SECTION 7. Appendix
>
> Theorem **7.1.** (Main lemma) 1 + 1 = 2

Notice that I'd like the theorem be numbered as "7.1." even in section 3. This *cannot* be done simply by copying and pasting, or by using packages like [clipboard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150790/how-to-make-text-be-copied-to-another-part-of-a-document).

Putting it differently, I'd like to copy a *specific region shown in the compiled file* and paste to another.

Comment: The `thmtools` package enables you to define *restatable* theorems. See §1.4, *Repeating theorems*, pp. 6-7 in the documentation.

Comment: @Bernard  I hope to put all my theorems in the appendix, which should be displayed at the end of the document. It seems that I cannot declare the restatable statement, and "recall" it in previous sections.. Is there any work-around?

Comment: Did you try to declare them in the appendix and recall them in advance? Possibly it would work after a second compilation. Other than that,  I  can see no workaround (which doesn't mean it's not possible).

Comment: @Bernard yes I tried it with two compilations. The error reads "! Undefined control sequence." Can I move the appendix section right after `\begin{docoment}`, but let the appendix be displayed as the last section? I hope then the undefined control sequence issue will be resolved.

Comment: What's the undefined control sequence?

Comment: As shown in the manual `\begin{restatable}[Euclid]{theorem}{firsteuclid}...\end...`, I put `\firsteuclid*` one line before the restatable declaration. Then the undefined control sequence is `! Undefined control sequence. \n l.1586 \firsteuclid`. Putting `\firsteuclid*` one line after the end of declaration worked fine.