# Delay presenting a section

Tags: macros, quoting

For some reason [1] I'd like to put some sections as the first section, but hope to present it at last.

Namely, I hope commands `\show` `\noshow` as follow exist..

```
\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}\noshow   % this should suppresses the whole section
..
\section{First section}
..
\section{Second section}
..
\show{\section{Appendix}}   % this should re-show the whole section
\end{document}
```

- [1] [Quoting from the same document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570941/quoting-from-the-same-document)

Comment: Why not just put the appendix last and change its number to 1? Or am I misunderstanding what you want to do..?

Comment: What should the numbering of that section look like? Appendix = 1, First section = 2, ... yet they're displayed in the sequence 2, 3, 1?

Comment: @Werner yes.  #schtandard: because I'm trying to restate statements using `thmtools` as mentioned in [1].. it needs the appendix section to show up prior to others in the source..

Comment: (a) don't use `\show` as that is a tex primitive, (b) why not simply put the section at the end and adjust the numbering (this would be much easier)

Comment: I hope `\section{Appendix}` to appear right after `\begin{document}`..

Comment: @Student: What is the motivation for keeping it there?

Comment: why do you want it there in the source, it's not impossible but it just makes it harder to make the output you want

Comment: @Werner I apologize if I didn't make it clear. It's ultimately because a reason given in the link [1]. I want to use `thmtools` to restate statements. The idea is that all messy lemmas and proofs should be shown in the appendix, displayed in the end of the document; and I want to "call" them in my main text. The main crux is that package does not compile successfully, if the calling  appears **before** the called statement in the source file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah it has been tough :( .. I stated again why I'd hope such thing in the previous comment..

Comment: It seems very odd if forward references are not allowed. If you are getting errors with that it may be better to post that as the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the comment. I have posted it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572111/restate-statements-before-declaration)