# v/+v-argument-type which keeps the verbatim-delimiter?

Tags: verbatim, xparse

Assume you use **xparse** and have

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\macro}{+m}{%
   \addcontentsline{foo}{#1}%
}%
```

With `\macro{some text}` you get into the .aux-file something like `\@writefile{foo}{some text}`.

From time to time I wish to have processed material tokenized under verbatim-catcode-régime in a similar way. I.e.,

```
\verbmacro|some text
some text
some text|
```

should (with `\newlinechar=\endlinechar` and immediate-writing for ensuring that the change of `\newlinechar` is in effect while writing to the aux-file) in the .aux-file yield something like:

```
\@writeVerbatimArgFile{foo}|some text
some text
some text|
```

`\@writeVerbatimArgFile` could process its second argument as `+v`-type argument.

The crucial point is:

If you make `\verbmacro`'s argument a `+v`-type-argument, the surrounding verbatim-delimiter is stripped off. But it is needed because it shall appear in the .aux-file, in the `\@writeVerbatimArgFile`-entry, also.

Therefore my question is:

Does adding to **xparse** a `v`/`+v`-like argument-type where the verbatim-delimiter does not get removed make sense?

Do people who would use this belong to such a small minority that implementing that in **xparse** is not worth the efforts?

Please, don't misunderstand me: This is not intended as a "Do-it-for-me!"-question. I already have my own routines (not based on **xparse**) for doing such things. E.g., the routine `\UDcollectverbarg` in the second example of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518479/118714) to the question "[Unique requirement IDs and list of corresponding test method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518243/118714)" collects verbatimized arguments both without and with the delimiter.

The question is: Would such an argument type be used often enough that the effort of implementing it and spending memory resources for storing the underlying macro-mechanisms would be worthwhile?

---

At first glimpse you could think of defining `\verbmacro` in a way where `|` is prepended and appended to the `+v`-type-argument before writing to the .aux-file.

If you did that, you could not do things like

```
\verbmacro?some text with | in it?
```

any more.

With a hardcoded `|` you would get a `\@writeVerbatimArgFile`-entry like this:

```
\@writeVerbatimArgFile{foo}|some text with | in it|
```

This might be a problem.

If the verbatim-delimiter is not hardcoded but passed on, you get:

```
\@writeVerbatimArgFile{foo}?some text with | in it?
```

, which should not be a problem...

Comment: It wouldn't be particularly hard to implement this (in fact, the begin marker is stored in the grabbed argument for most part of the `xparse`-ing process, so probably just a minor tweak), but it would probably make an awkward argument type, mostly because other verbatim-like commands “remove” the delimiter. Why not just write a pair of `|...|` around the argument?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I added a remark to my question. If you somewhere "hardcode" the verbatim-delimiter instead of passing it on, you are bound to always using the hardcoded verbatim-delimiter...

Comment: Oh, right, that makes sense. It would be quite easy to patch the `v` argument to _always_ keep the delimiters (two copies of the first delimiter, actually): `\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_v_aux_loop_end: { \__xparse_grab_v_group_end: \__xparse_add_arg:x { \exp_not:V \l__xparse_v_arg_tl \tl_head:N \l__xparse_v_arg_tl } }`. To have it be a _new_ argument type you'd probably need to copy the entire definition of the `v` type argument and change that bit.

Comment: I'm not yet  - I intend to become. ;-)  - familiar enough with expl3-syntax and xparse's internals for seeing it myself immediately:  Does this take into account the case of the verbatim-arg being wrapped in `{` and `}` (which is possible with `v`/`+v`-arguments)? In this case first and second delimiter differ, thus in this case the phrase "two copies of the *first* delimiter" might not describe the situation correctly...

Comment: No, that's exactly it, two copies of the first delimiter. For a `v`-type argument, `xparse` will grab it token by token, and store that in the `\l__xparse_v_arg_tl` token list _along with_ the first delimiter so, say, `\test|hello|` would end up as `|hello` in `\l__xparse_v_arg_tl` at the time `\__xparse_grab_v_aux_loop_end:` is expanded. `xparse`'s code does `\__xparse_add_arg:x { \tl_tail:N \l__xparse_v_arg_tl }`, which removes the leading token from `\l__xparse_v_arg_tl` and then flushes it as an argument to the current macro. [...]

Comment: [...] My patch above changes that to the _entire_ token list `\l__xparse_v_arg_tl`, plus its first token (`\tl_head:N`), so yes, if you did `\test{hello}` you'd end up with `{hello{`. If you insist, here's a version that works for `\test{hello}`: `\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_v_aux_loop_end: { \__xparse_grab_v_group_end: \__xparse_add_arg:x { \exp_not:V \l__xparse_v_arg_tl \str_if_eq:eeTF { \tl_head:N \l__xparse_v_arg_tl } { \c_left_brace_str } { \c_right_brace_str } { \tl_head:N \l__xparse_v_arg_tl } } }`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  Thanks a lot. I think I will need an hour or five until I have retraced both the original definition and the patch in sufficient depth... ;-)