# Aligning text in S columns in a way that respects the decimal marker for numerical entries

Tags: horizontal-alignment, siunitx

As I understand it, using various options for the `S` column in `siunitx`, I may produce columns containing both numerical and nonnumerical entries. I may have the numerical entries aligned at their decimal points. I may have the text entries either left-, right-, or center- justified with respect to the column's width.

*Is it possible to have the numerical entries aligned by their decimal, while controlling the text entries' alignment as it relates to the decimal marker?*

To complicate things further, is it possible to apply alignments differently row by row? In particular, could I leave column-centered alignment for the head entry of a column, while making my special decimal marker-based alignment apply to later entries?

The following MWE sort of produces what I want with exaggerated numbers, but I have manually forced some space in the last two entries to make it happen. I want to not have to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\newcommand*\heading[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=9.3,table-text-alignment=center]}
\hline
\heading{Title}\\
\hline
1\\
2.000\\
6\\
24.0\\
123456789\\
{\phantom{123\,456\,78}\vdots\phantom{\,000}}\\
{\phantom{123\,456\,7}$f(n)$\phantom{\,00}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: *enter image description here*]

Note that I do want a centered title, and that ideally I actually want the remaining text entries centered with respect to a point that is roughly `0.5\ex` to the left of the decimal marker. Also, note that since I have such asymmetry between integer an fractional parts, I do not think that `table-number-alignment=center-decimal-marker` is helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant with “apply alignments differently row by row”. Isn't that what you get with your `\heading` macro?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for your answer - I will try to apply it Monday when I again have access to my desktop. I believe that in my experiments, the text alignment from S was overriding the alignment c in my `\heading` macro. As I recall parameters like `table-text-alignment=left` made the c in my `\heading` command pointless. I may be misremembering though - I went through a lot of experimentation this morning.

Comment: I just updated my answer so that is easier useable. If I understand it correctly, `\multicolumn` overrides SIunitx's stuff. And “Title” was actually typeset centered to the whole column …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Sorry for the confusion - in my MWE the Title is centered fine, and even better, without any manual spacing. Ideally, I would like a siunitx solution to my problem with text-at-decimal alignment - perhaps defining a new fourth option for `table-text-align`. I want to emphasize that such a solution should leave my heading alone, and still be overrideable by \multicolumn. Hopefully, this is not actually an issue.

Comment: Than just type `{Title}` or use your `\multicolumn` solution. Implementing this inside of SIunitx is out of my skillset as it uses heavily LaTeX3 code. This is probably something for [the developer of SIunitx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright).

Comment: @alex.jordan Reading over the question and current answer, it seems this essentially boils down to a feature request. You seem to want an option `table-text-align = decimal-center`, so align text relative to the decimal. Is that correct? Different alignments in different parts of a column are not really possible in a fully-automated, as table content is collected before being processed at all. As such, you will probably have to handle table headings using `\multicolumn` with the option I suggest.

Comment: I'd also note that the business about wanting an alignment with offset is really outside of what `siunitx` was designed to handle. The intention of the `S` column is to align numerical columns, which it does a reasonable job of, but if you have very specific needs then there comes a point at which a custom solution is the best way forward.

Comment: Logged for v2.6: https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/issue/205/align-text-based-on-decimal-marker (probably over the Christmas holidays).

Comment: @Joseph Wright At first I hoped there may be some way to access decimal alignment for text; some sort of width that was part of the package but not mentioned in the documentation. I suppose it is indeed a feature request though. Thank you for putting it under consideration!

Answer (score 10):

Let me say two things before:

1. This is not an only-`siunitx` solution. Sadly, `table-text-alignment` doesn't take `decimal-marker` :(
2. I provide two macros:

   1. `\widestparts{<digits before …>}{<… and after decimal marker>}`<sup>†</sup>
   2. `\tcenter{<text to center at the decimal marker>}`

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>This works now, thanks to [Peter Grill's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14393/16595), [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14394/16595) and [Peter's hint in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6654924#6654924).</sub>

#### Manual aligning

You can add another `\textcenter` macro that takes three arguments:

1. stuff before your actual text,
2. stuff after your actual text (in the example below I also removed the decimal marker `.`), and
3. stuff that gets actually typeset.

For example:

```
\newcommand*{\textcenter}[3]{{%
    \hphantom{\num{#1}}%
    \makebox[\widthof{.}][c]{#3}\hspace{-\decimalmarkerwidth}%
    \hphantom{\num[add-decimal-zero = false,add-integer-zero = false,scientific-notation = fixed]{#2}}%
}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % only for this example (redefinition of hphantom}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc,siunitx,ifthen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% getting the width of the decimal marker: . or ,
\newlength{\decimalmarkerwidth}\settowidth{\decimalmarkerwidth}{.} % or ,

% remove the % in the next line to get gray phantoms
%\renewcommand\hphantom[1]{{\color[gray]{.7}#1}}

\newcommand*\heading[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % not used anymore ... (but can used (without the multicolumn) for other formatting (bf, color, ...)

\makeatletter
\newcounter{alex@auxctr} % (Internal)

% \widestparts takes two arguments: #1 = number of digits before the decimal marker
                                  % #2 = number of digits after the decimal marker
\newcommand*{\widestparts}[2]{%
    \alex@widestpartauxloop{\alex@widestpartleft}{#1}{9}%
    \alex@widestpartauxloop{\alex@widestpartright}{#2}{0}%
}

% (Internal) \alex@widestpartauxloop loops over #2 and adds #2 times #3 to #1.
\newcommand*{\alex@widestpartauxloop}[3]{%
    \def\alex@WidestPartTemp{}\setcounter{alex@auxctr}{0}%
    \whiledo{\value{alex@auxctr}<#2}{\g@addto@macro\alex@WidestPartTemp{#3}\stepcounter{alex@auxctr}}%
    \xdef#1{\alex@WidestPartTemp}%
}

% \tcenter takes one argument: #1 = actual text that should be typeset
\newcommand*{\tcenter}[1]{{%
    \hphantom{\num{\alex@widestpartleft}}%
    \makebox[\widthof{.}][c]{#1}\hspace{-\decimalmarkerwidth}%
    \hphantom{\num[add-decimal-zero = false,add-integer-zero = false,scientific-notation = fixed]{.\alex@widestpartright}}%
}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{booktabs} % for \top-, \mid- and \bottomrule

\begin{document}
\widestparts{9}{3}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=9.3,table-text-alignment=center]}
    \toprule
             \tcenter{Title}            \\ \midrule
                    1                   \\
                  2.000                 \\
                    6                   \\
                   24.0                 \\
                123456789               \\
    \tcenter{$\smash{\vdotswithin{.}}$} \\ % \smash is used to hide the oversized vertical height of \vdots
             \tcenter{$f(n)$}           \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output with phantomed hidden stuff] 
[image: Output with gray hidden stuff]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't play around with this until Monday, but at a glance I have a concern. I am working on a very long document with hundreds of tables like this. And I very much want a solution at the level of `S`. That is, I won't want to have to put anything more than a pair of braces around my non-numeric table entries, let `siunitx` and `S` detect what is numeric and what is not, and typeset accordingly. Can I modify `S` to wrap your `tcenter` around non-numeric entries?

Comment: @alex.jordan: That might be a separate question, but you could possibly use [the `collcell ` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) for that, although I don't think I have tried it with the `S` column.