# Align math contents in a table

Tags: horizontal-alignment, siunitx, tabu

While trying to display some data in a table, I use `tabu` and `siunitx`. I want the content to be centered by the dot. However, the cell at last column, first row is not centered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newcolumntype Y{S[%
    group-four-digits=false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3,
    round-integer-to-decimal=false,
    per-mode=symbol,
    detect-all,
    ]}
\tabucolumn Y
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
    \def\NN{\tabularnewline}
    \def\FL{\toprule}
    \def\ML{\NN\midrule}
    \def\LL{\NN\bottomrule}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{|c|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
    \FL
    $K$ & {2} & {5} & {10} & {100}
    \ML
    $\gamma_3$ & 0.13731 & 0.14011 & 0.11446 & 0.040306
    \NN
    $\gamma_4$ & -0.22974 & -0.069162 & -0.17112 & 0.11587
    \LL
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your question similar to [Aligning text in S columns in a way that respects the decimal marker for numerical entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79221) I wonder if the 'standard' `\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}` trick could work for you?

Comment: I tried that. It does the trick, however a global solution would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem arises because of the way you have 'hidden' the end-of-row inside another macro. Picking up the last cell in the row correctly is tricky, and this leads to the need to do various pieces of detection inside the package. However, that fails if the `\\` (or `\tabularnewline`) is inside another command. As such, the best way to deal with this is to replace `\ML` with `\\ \midrule` here.

Comment: I tried to use

`\makeatletter
    \def\NN{\\}
    \def\FL{\toprule}
    \def\ML{\NN\midrule}
    \def\LL{\NN\bottomrule}
\makeatother`

and doing that way it did work. Any clue?