# Can I get a list of all sections as a simple enumerate-list?

Tags: sectioning, lists, enumerate

I am currently creating a template for transcripts (I don't know if this is the right word: you write a transcript if you have a (business) meeting and you want to record all important stuff that was said). The source is [here](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/blob/master/documents/protokoll/protokoll.tex).

The agenda items are currently in a simple `enumerate`-environment **and** as `\section*` in the source code. I would like to have only the `section*{agenda item}` written by the transcript writer. The list of all agenda items should get generated automatically. Ist this possible?

(Just to make that clear: I don't want to insert a table of contents! I want a simple

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.3em]%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-2pt}% 
    \item agenda item 1
    \item agenda item 2
    \item agenda item 3
    \item agenda item 4
\end{enumerate}
```

which gets generated automatically)

Comment: It seems to me that _is_ a table of contents, just with different formatting. Or at least that would be the most natural way to implement it in latex. just define `\l@section` which defines what is written to the `toc` file to write `\item`.

Comment: Is the template based on the `article` class? Are there also numbered sections or not?

Comment: I use `scrartcl` class. No, I only use unnumbered sections (`section*{bla}`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution: the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package was used to suppress the numbering for `\section`s in the document body; a redefinition of `\l@section` and `\tableofcontents` give the desired formatting as a list:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\@starttoc{toc}
}
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{0.5em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.3em}%
    \begingroup
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      #1\hfil\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{}{0em}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Agenda item one}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item three}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item four}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

An image of the firs page, showing the list of sections:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I modify a little Gonzalo's method, in order to not hard-code the spacings and really use rather a true `enumerate` environment. (edit: to illustrate I add a `\usepackage{enumerate}`.) (edit2: I amend my original code which, in the case of options passed to the enumerate environment, compiled only if the `toc` file already existed...)

---

Edited: I propose three increasingly complicated methods. The first was a modification of `Gonzalo`'s approach, in order to allow to use a real enumerate environment. For that, `egreg` has since provided a yet simpler way. Then I added support for subsections and subsubsections so that one could use formatting options of packages like `enumitem` to customize the look of the hacked table of contents (method 2). Finally (method 3) I modify once more to add `hyperref` support. So in the end we reconstitute a mock table of contents with possible hyperlinks. The links are put in the names of sections and subsections, but could also be inserted in the labels of the item (using `enumitem`). Page numbers are just not used. But if I understand the OP's aim would be more to use here an `itemize` environment, so I did not try to put the links in the item labels.

Here is for example how a table of contents with sections, subsections and subsubsections may appear:

[image: example of a hacked table of contents]

And all names (or letters for the subsubsections) are `hyperref`-links (the names are the ones used in the document body for the titles of the sections, subsections, subsubsections, they are not generated by the code). The code to get this is the third proposal below.

---

First proposal:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newtoks\agendatoks
\newif\ifexisttoc

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\@starttoc{toc}\ifexisttoc
\begin{enumerate}[(A)] % <- customize this, for example if you use the
                  % enumitem package, to specify the spacings etc...
\the\agendatoks
\end{enumerate}
\fi}

\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \let\ex\expandafter
  \let\numberline\@gobble
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
  \toks0=\ex{\ex\item #1}%
  \global\agendatoks=\ex\ex\ex{\ex\the\ex\agendatoks\the\toks0}%
  \global\existtoctrue
 \fi}

\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{}{0em}{}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\section{Agenda item one}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item three}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item four}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Caveat: I did not look more than casually at the contents of a `.toc` file, so the method is only tested on <strike>the OP's</strike> Gonzalo's example!

[image: png image of the dvi file]

---

Second proposal:

```
% Time-stamp: <30-10-2012 21:26:48 CET jfb>
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79682/can-i-get-a-list-of-all-sections-as-a-simple-enumerate-list

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % to use its formatting options for enumerate, itemize, description
\usepackage{titlesec}  % to generate unnumbered sections and subsections in the body

%------------ macros to format the table of contents to one's arbitrary wishes
%------------ use is self-explanatory: customize \headeri, \headerii, \headeriii
%------------ none of the above two packages is necessary for the working of the macros

\newtoks\agendatoks
\newif\ifexisti
\newif\ifexistii
\newif\ifexistiii
\makeatletter

%------------ here we use options made available by package enumitem
\newcommand\headeri{\begin{enumerate}[font=\LARGE,label=\fbox{\arabic*}, itemsep=24pt]}
\newcommand\footeri{\end{enumerate}} % keep it in sync with \headeri!

\newcommand\headerii{\begin{enumerate}[font=\ttfamily\bfseries, leftmargin=1.5cm,%
 itemsep=18pt]}
\newcommand\footerii{\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand\headeriii{\begin{itemize}[itemsep=12pt]}
\newcommand\footeriii{\end{itemize}} 

%------------ our beautiful macros
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\@starttoc{toc}%
\ifexisti
\the\agendatoks
\ifexistiii\footeriii\fi
\ifexistii\footerii\fi
\footeri
\fi}

\renewcommand\l@section[2]{%
  \let\ex\expandafter
  \let\numberline\@gobble
  \ifexistiii\toks0=\ex{\footeriii}\else\toks0={}\fi
  \global\existiiifalse
  \ifexistii\toks0=\ex{\the\toks0\noexpand\footerii}\fi
  \global\existiifalse
  \ifexisti\else\toks0=\ex{\headeri}\fi
  \global\existitrue
  \toks0=\ex{\the\toks0\noexpand\item}%
  \toks0=\ex\ex\ex{\ex\the\ex\toks0#1}%
  \global\agendatoks=\ex\ex\ex{\ex\the\ex\agendatoks\the\toks0}%
  % \showthe\agendatoks % for debugging
}

\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{%
  \let\ex\expandafter
  \let\numberline\@gobble
  \ifexistiii\toks0=\ex{\footeriii}\else\toks0={}\fi
  \global\existiiifalse
  \ifexistii\else\toks0=\ex{\headerii}\fi
  \global\existiitrue
  \toks0=\ex{\the\toks0\noexpand\item}%
  \toks0=\ex\ex\ex{\ex\the\ex\toks0#1}%
  \global\agendatoks=\ex\ex\ex{\ex\the\ex\agendatoks\the\toks0}%
  % \showthe\agendatoks
}

\renewcommand\l@subsubsection[2]{%
  \let\ex\expandafter
  \let\numberline\@gobble
  \ifexistiii\toks0={}\else\toks0=\ex{\headeriii}\fi
  \global\existiiitrue
  \toks0=\ex{\the\toks0\noexpand\item}%
  \toks0=\ex\ex\ex{\ex\the\ex\toks0#1}%
  \global\agendatoks=\ex\ex\ex{\ex\the\ex\agendatoks\the\toks0}%
  % \showthe\agendatoks
}

\makeatother

% the following (from package titlesec) only influences the look of the body,
% not the table of contents
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\large\ttfamily}{}{2em}{}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\centerline{\bfseries THIS IS THE TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\subsection{primo}
\subsection{secondo}
\subsubsection{i}
\subsubsection{ii}
\subsection{tertio}
\subsubsection{i}
\subsubsection{ii}
\subsubsection{iii}
\section{Second}
\subsection{primo}
\subsubsection{i}
\subsubsection{ii}
\subsubsection{iii}
\subsection{secondo}
\section{Third}
\subsection{tertio}
\section{Fourth}
\subsection{quarto}
\subsubsection{i}
\subsubsection{ii}
\subsubsection{iii}

\end{document}
```

Here is the first page:

[image]

---

Third proposal: with `hyperref` support (works also if `hyperref` is not there)

```
% Time-stamp: <31-10-2012 10:56:36 CET jfb>
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79682/can-i-get-a-list-of-all-sections-as-a-simple-enumerate-list

% Third version: now compatible with hyperref.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % to use its formatting options for enumerate, itemize, description
\usepackage{titlesec}  % to generate unnumbered sections and subsections in the body
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtoks\agendatoks
\newif\ifexisti
\newif\ifexistii
\newif\ifexistiii


%------------ here we use options made available by package enumitem
%------------ for the top level, and redefine \item for the inner levels

\makeatletter

\newcommand\headeri{\begin{enumerate}[font=\LARGE, %
                label=\fbox{\arabic*}, itemsep=18pt]%
                \sffamily\bfseries\Large}
\newcommand\footeri{\end{enumerate}} % keep it in sync with \headeri!

\newcommand\headerii{ \begingroup\normalfont\ttfamily(\def\item{, }\@gobble}
\newcommand\footerii{)\endgroup}

\newcommand\headeriii{\begingroup\scshape
                \let\item-$^\bgroup\hbox\bgroup\scriptsize\@gobble}
\newcommand\footeriii{\egroup\egroup$\endgroup} 

\makeatother


%------------ our beautiful macros
\makeatletter

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\@starttoc{toc}%
\ifexisti
\the\agendatoks
\ifexistiii\footeriii\fi
\ifexistii\footerii\fi
\footeri
\fi}

\renewcommand\l@section[2]{%
  \let\@xp\expandafter
  \let\numberline\@gobble
  \def\hyper@linkstart{\noexpand\hyper@linkstart}%
  \def\hyper@linkend{\noexpand\hyper@linkend}%
  \edef\@jfbutmp{#1}%
  \ifexistiii\toks0={\footeriii}\else\toks0={}\fi
  \global\existiiifalse
  \ifexistii\toks0=\@xp{\the\toks0 \footerii}\fi 
  \global\existiifalse
  \ifexisti\else\toks0={\headeri}\fi  
  \global\existitrue
  \toks0=\@xp{\the\toks0 \item}% 
  \toks0=\@xp{\the\toks0\@jfbutmp}%
  \global\agendatoks=\@xp\@xp\@xp{\@xp\the\@xp\agendatoks\the\toks0}%
}

\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{%
  \let\@xp\expandafter
  \let\numberline\@gobble
  \def\hyper@linkstart{\noexpand\hyper@linkstart}%
  \def\hyper@linkend{\noexpand\hyper@linkend}%
  \edef\@jfbutmp{#1}%
  \ifexistiii\toks0={\footeriii}\else\toks0={}\fi
  \global\existiiifalse
  \ifexistii\else\toks0={\headerii}\fi
  \global\existiitrue
  \toks0=\@xp{\the\toks0 \item}%
  \toks0=\@xp{\the\toks0\@jfbutmp}
  \global\agendatoks=\@xp\@xp\@xp{\@xp\the\@xp\agendatoks\the\toks0}
}

\renewcommand\l@subsubsection[2]{%
  \let\@xp\expandafter
  \let\numberline\@gobble
  \def\hyper@linkstart{\noexpand\hyper@linkstart}%
  \def\hyper@linkend{\noexpand\hyper@linkend}%
  \edef\@jfbutmp{#1}%
  \ifexistiii\toks0={}\else\toks0={\headeriii}\fi
  \global\existiiitrue
  \toks0=\@xp{\the\toks0 \item}%
  \toks0=\@xp{\the\toks0\@jfbutmp}%
  \global\agendatoks=\@xp\@xp\@xp{\@xp\the\@xp\agendatoks\the\toks0}%
}

\makeatother


% the following (from package titlesec) only influences the look of the body,
% not the table of contents
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\large\ttfamily}{}{2em}{}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\kant[1]
\subsection{primo}
\kant[11]
\subsection{secondo}
\kant[12]
\subsubsection{i}
\kant[121]
\subsubsection{ii}
\kant[122]
\subsection{tertio}
\kant[13]
\subsubsection{i}
\kant[131]
\subsubsection{ii}
\kant[132]
\subsubsection{iii}
\kant[133]
\section{Second}
\kant[2]
\subsection{primo}
\kant[21]
\subsubsection{i}
\kant[111]
\subsubsection{ii}
\kant[112]
\subsubsection{iii}
\kant[113]
\subsection{secondo}
\kant[22]
\section{Third}
\kant[3]
\subsection{tertio}
\kant[33]
\section{Fourth}
\kant[4]
\subsection{quarto}
\kant[44]
\subsubsection{i}
\kant[141]
\subsubsection{ii}
\kant[142]
\subsubsection{iii}
\kant[143]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the `\toks0` lines of the code, the `\noexpand` before `\item` or `\footerii` can be replaced by a space. Furthermore, `\toks0=\ex{\the\toks0\@jfbutmp}` works because TeX expands `\@jfbutmp` (looking if it gives a digit). I leave `\toks0=\ex\ex\ex{\ex\the\ex\toks0\@jfbutmp}` as is with its many `\expandafter` as it is  simpler to understand while reading it what it does.

Comment: I have in fact now edited the code to use the trick from my comment above to have less `\expandafter`'s. Also I remove some other expansion so that the token list `\agendatoks` works the same way but is shorter.

Comment: The macros here are not compatible with having certain types of commands inside section or subsection names. Slightly different macros achieve this, still in an `hyperref` compatible way. But this goes a bit too far from the original question so I leave things as they stand.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version that uses [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time)
to store the titles of all the `\section*{}`, and then this can be printed in an enumerated list at the end.  So, with a document as:

```
\begin{document}
\section{First Non Starred Section}
\section*{First Starred section}
\section*{Second Starred section}

\section{Second Non Starred Section}
\section*{Third Starred section}
\section*{Fourth Starred section}
\end{document}
```

we get the following at the end of the document:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to distinguish between `\section` and `\section*` as I prefer it's syntax, but it should be possible to implement the same functionality without it.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time
\def\ListOfSectionTitles{}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\AddSectionTitle}[1]{\g@addto@macro\ListOfSectionTitles{{\item #1}}}
\makeatother

\let\OldSection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        % This is a starred section, so store it's title
        \AddSectionTitle{#2}%
        \OldSection*{#2}%
    }{%
        \OldSection{#2}%
    }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \textbf{List of Starred Sections:}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \ListOfSectionTitles
    \end{enumerate}
}%

\begin{document}
\section{First Non Starred Section}
\section*{First Starred section}
\section*{Second Starred section}

\section{Second Non Starred Section}
\section*{Third Starred section}
\section*{Fourth Starred section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess that this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\@starttoc{toc}}
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{\item #1}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{enumerate}}}
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{enumerate}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Agenda item one}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item three}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Agenda item four}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]