# Expansion issue when adding to CSV list from within a \foreach

Tags: expansion, loops, foreach, comma-separated-list

Another expansion issue that I am unable to guess at the correct combination of `\edef`/`\expandafters` to get to work.

### Background:

Below I have defined `\AddToCommaSeparateList` which uses `\g@addto@macro` as per [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time).  This works as I desire when used outside of a `\foreach` and properly handles list members containing a comma:

[image]

### Problem:

But when I attempt to add to this list from within a `\foreach`, I run into an expansion issue.  Well the answer seems pretty obvious, I just need to expand the content that is added to the list. Well, that should not be too difficult, or so I think. So I defined `\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList`, where instead of

```
\g@addto@macro#1{{#2}}%      used in `\AddToCommaSeparateList`
```

I simply use:

```
\edef\ExpandedMember{#2}% 
\g@addto@macro#1{{\ExpandedMember}}%
```

Well, as is usual with expansion issues (at least for me), things did not quite work as expected. In the MWE below I had to resort to an `\xdef` to get things to compile, but I should only need an `\edef`.

[image]

### Question:

- What magic combination of `\edef` and/or `\expandafter`s do I need to add to the `\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList` macro so that I can use it outside and inside a `\foreach`?

### Notes:

- I think this code seems rather long, but I think that is due to the comments, and the first phase which is just to test that the code works as expected in basic usage.
- The problem output is highlighted in red, it should correspond to the output in blue.
- I really just want one version of this macro that works in both cases (inside and outside of a `\foreach`). Don't really see where I would *not* want expansion (at least in my use case). Hence, am tryinig to handle the expansion issue from within the macro that adds to the list, as opposed to within the `\foreach`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ResetCommaSeparatedList}[1]{\gdef#1{}}%
\newcommand*{\IfEmptyCommaSeparatedList}[3]{%
    % #1 = listname
    % #2 = code if list is empty
    % #3 = code if list is non-empty
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand*{\AddToCommaSeparateList}[2]{%
    % #1 = listname
    % #2 = content to add to CSV list
    %
    % Don't add a leading comma in list
    \IfEmptyCommaSeparatedList{#1}{}{\g@addto@macro#1{,}}%
    %
    %  Extra brace group in case #2 contains a comma
    \g@addto@macro#1{{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand*{\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList}[2]{% with expansion?
    % #1 = listname
    % #2 = content to add to CSV list
    %
    % Don't add a leading comma in list
    \IfEmptyCommaSeparatedList{#1}{}{\g@addto@macro#1{,}}%
    %
    % Only need a \edef here, but usign \xdef to get this to compile
    \xdef\ExpandedMember{#2}% 
    %  Extra brace group in case #2 contains a comma
    \g@addto@macro#1{{\ExpandedMember}}%
}%
\newcommand*{\DumpList}[1][black]{%
    \par
    MyList = \par
    \foreach \x in \MyList {\hspace*{1cm}\textcolor{#1}{\x}\par}
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\MyList}{}%

\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{Show that this works outside of foreach}\par
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{\MyList}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{1}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{2}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{3}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[blue]

% Repeat just to ensure that that \ResetCommaSeparatedList works
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{\MyList}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{x}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{y}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{z}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{a, b, c}
\DumpList

\bigskip\hrule
\bigskip\noindent
But, when the content is added via a \verb|\foreach| there are 
expansion issues.
I want this to yield \textcolor{blue}{1, 2, 3}:

% --------------------------------- Problems start here
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{\MyList}
\foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
    % A check is made here so that only certain ones get added
    % to the CSV list (omitted here as it is not relevant to issue)
    \ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{\x}%
}
\DumpList[red]

\bigskip\noindent
Also, would prefer just one version of this macro, so this should 
produce results identical to the first output in blue above:
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{\MyList}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{1}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{2}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{3}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[red]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative version without `\ExpandedMember` and with no `\expandafter`:

```
\newcommand*{\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList}[2]{% with expansion?
    % #1 = listname
    % #2 = content to add to CSV list
    %
    % Don't add a leading comma in list
    \IfEmptyCommaSeparatedList{#1}{}{\g@addto@macro#1{,}}%
    %  Extra brace group in case #2 contains a comma
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand#1{{#2}}}\x
}
```

The grouping around `\edef\x` is just to ensure that `\x` won't be available after its own expansion. It's defined in a group and its expansion closes the group, so the definition vanishes.

---

A LaTeX3 implementation. There is one big change: instead of a control sequence a name is given to the list (I also changed a couple of macro names for uniformity)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetCommaSeparatedList} { m }
 {
  \clist_gclear_new:c { g_grill_list_ #1 _clist }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddToCommaSeparatedList} { m m }
 {
  % #1 = listname
  % #2 = content to add to CSV list
  %
  \clist_gput_right:cn { g_grill_list_ #1 _clist } { {#2} } 
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparatedList} { m m }
 {
  % #1 = listname
  % #2 = content to add to CSV list
  \clist_gput_right:cx { g_grill_list_ #1 _clist } { {#2} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\DumpList} { O{black} m }
 {
  \par
  #2 = \par
  \clist_map_inline:cn { g_grill_list_ #2 _clist }
   {
    \hspace*{1cm}\textcolor{#1}{##1}\par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\Gx}{1}
\newcommand{\Gy}{2}
\newcommand{\Gz}{3}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{Show that this works}\par
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{MyList}
\AddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{1}
\AddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{2}
\AddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{3}
\AddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[blue]{MyList}

% Repeat just to ensure that that \ResetCommaSeparatedList works
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{MyList}
\AddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{x}
\AddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{y}
\AddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{z}
\AddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{a, b, c}
\DumpList{MyList}

\ResetCommaSeparatedList{MyList}
\foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
    \ExpandedAddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{\x}%
}
\DumpList[red]{MyList}

\bigskip
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{MyList}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{\Gx}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{\Gy}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{\Gz}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparatedList{MyList}{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[red]{MyList}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Actually, sequences would be better suited for this application (no need of additional braces, for instance, and probably faster processing).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetList} { m }
 {
  \seq_gclear_new:c { g_grill_list_ #1 _seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddToList} { m m }
 {
  % #1 = listname
  % #2 = content to add to list
  %
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_grill_list_ #1 _seq } { #2 } 
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\ExpandedAddToList} { m m }
 {
  % #1 = listname
  % #2 = content to add to list
  \seq_gput_right:cx { g_grill_list_ #1 _seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\DumpList} { O{black} m }
 {
  \par
  #2 = \par
  \seq_map_inline:cn { g_grill_list_ #2 _seq }
   {
    \hspace*{1cm}\textcolor{#1}{##1}\par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\Gx}{1}
\newcommand{\Gy}{2}
\newcommand{\Gz}{3}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{Show that this works}\par
\ResetList{MyList}
\AddToList{MyList}{1}
\AddToList{MyList}{2}
\AddToList{MyList}{3}
\AddToList{MyList}{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[blue]{MyList}

% Repeat just to ensure that that \ResetList works
\ResetList{MyList}
\AddToList{MyList}{x}
\AddToList{MyList}{y}
\AddToList{MyList}{z}
\AddToList{MyList}{a, b, c}
\DumpList{MyList}

\ResetList{MyList}
\foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
    \ExpandedAddToList{MyList}{\x}%
}
\DumpList[red]{MyList}

\bigskip
\ResetList{MyList}
\ExpandedAddToList{MyList}{\Gx}
\ExpandedAddToList{MyList}{\Gy}
\ExpandedAddToList{MyList}{\Gz}
\ExpandedAddToList{MyList}{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[red]{MyList}
\end{document}
```

You may be willing to add

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ExpandedOnceAddToList} { m m }
 {
  % #1 = listname
  % #2 = content to add to list
  \seq_gput_right:co { g_grill_list_ #1 _seq } { #2 }
 }
```

for use with `\foreach`, so that in

```
\ResetList{MyList}
\foreach \x in {\Gx,\Gy,\Gz} {%
    \ExpandedOnceAddToList{MyList}{\x}%
}
```

the auxiliary macro `\x` would be expanded just once and the list would contain `\Gx`, `\Gy` and `\Gz` rather than their expansions.

Answer (score 4):

You want to add the expansion of `\ExpandedMember`, not `\ExpandedMember` itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ResetCommaSeparatedList}[1]{\gdef#1{}}%
\newcommand*{\IfEmptyCommaSeparatedList}[3]{%
    % #1 = listname
    % #2 = code if list is empty
    % #3 = code if list is non-empty
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand*{\AddToCommaSeparateList}[2]{%
    % #1 = listname
    % #2 = content to add to CSV list
    %
    % Don't add a leading comma in list
    \IfEmptyCommaSeparatedList{#1}{}{\g@addto@macro#1{,}}%
    %
    %  Extra brace group in case #2 contains a comma
    \g@addto@macro#1{{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand*{\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList}[2]{% with expansion?
    % #1 = listname
    % #2 = content to add to CSV list
    %
    % Don't add a leading comma in list
    \IfEmptyCommaSeparatedList{#1}{}{\g@addto@macro#1{,}}%
    %
    % Only need a \edef here, but usign \xdef to get this to compile
    \edef\ExpandedMember{#2}% 
    %  Extra brace group in case #2 contains a comma
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter{\ExpandedMember}}%
}%
\newcommand*{\DumpList}[1][black]{%
    \par
    MyList = \par
    \foreach \x in \MyList {\hspace*{1cm}\textcolor{#1}{\x}\par}
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\MyList}{}%

\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{Show that this works outside of foreach}\par
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{\MyList}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{1}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{2}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{3}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[blue]

% Repeat just to ensure that that \ResetCommaSeparatedList works
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{\MyList}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{x}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{y}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{z}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{a, b, c}
\DumpList

\bigskip\hrule
\bigskip\noindent
But, when the content is added via a \verb|\foreach| there are 
expansion issues.
I want this to yield \textcolor{blue}{1, 2, 3}:

% --------------------------------- Problems start here
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{\MyList}
\foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
    % A check is made here so that only certain ones get added
    % to the CSV list (omitted here as it is not relevant to issue)
    \ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{\x}%
}
\DumpList[red]

\bigskip\noindent
Also, would prefer just one version of this macro, so this should 
produce results identical to the first output in blue above:
\ResetCommaSeparatedList{\MyList}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{1}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{2}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{3}
\ExpandedAddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[red]
\end{document}
```

Comment: One does not need to define `\ExpandedMember`; just say `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup \unexpanded{\g@addto@macro#1}{{#2}}}\x`

Comment: @egreg: Right, but I thought it might be helpful to explain why the current solution wasn't working.

Comment: Both work. I can _almost_ follow this solution. @egreg's almost makes sense too (now that I have looked at it for a few minutes), except for the grouping issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill: and to see how easy things are with `expl3` in case you are interested, if you `\usepackage{expl3}` then the `\ExpandedMember` stuff can be replaced with `\csname exp_args:NNx\endcsname\g@addto@macro#1{{#2}}` (the `\csname...\endcsname` is to avoid having to switch to `expl3` syntax). Much clearer I think.

Comment: To explain the `\expandafter`s, I think of it as meaning "skip the next **token**, expand the following **token**" (and the `\expandafter` itself gets eaten). In this case the following token in all but the last case is another `\expandafter`, to skip enough tokens (`\g@addto@macro` then `#1` which I assume is one token as another macro is expected there, then a brace and another brace) until we eventually expand `\ExpandedMember`, which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Since your comment suggests that your list might contain macro elements, `\AddToCommaList` will expand the accretion if `\mywrapper` is, say, `\@firstofone`. For now, `\mywrapper` adds outer braces to (and expands) accreted elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{loops}[2012/10/16]
\newcommand*\ResetCommaList[1]{\gdef#1{}}
% You can change \mywrapper to format added items:
\newcommand*\mywrapper[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand*\MyList{}
% Expand new item while adding:
\newcommand*\AddToCommaList[2]{\edef#1{\skvaddlist,#1\mywrapper{#2}}}
\newcommand*\DumpList[1][black]{%
  \par MyList = \par
  % PGF's \foreach will normally assume \MyList to contain the elements of 
  % the list. Since a list may be made up of \macro items, \foreachfox 
  % doesn't make that assumption. So you would need to tell it to expand 
  % the list. This can be done using the keys 'list is a macro', 
  % 'expand list once', 'expand list twice', etc.
  \foreachfox [list is a macro] \MyList {%
    \hspace*{1cm}\textcolor{#1}{##1}\endgraf
  }%
}
\def\MyListOfValues{Rancheria, Paiute, Pascua, Paskenta}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{Show that this works outside of foreach}\par
\ResetCommaList\MyList
\AddToCommaList\MyList\MyListOfValues
\AddToCommaList\MyList{1}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{2}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{3}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[blue]

% Repeat printing:
\ResetCommaList\MyList
\AddToCommaList\MyList{x}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{y}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{z}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{a, b, c}
\DumpList

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent

\ResetCommaList\MyList
\def\ignoredlist{3,B}
\foreachfox {1,...,4,A,...,D} {%
  % Decide if new item should be added:
  \skvxiffound{,#1,}\in{,\ignoredlist,}\then\else
    \AddToCommaList\MyList{#1}%
  \fi
}
\DumpList[red]

\bigskip\noindent
\ResetCommaList\MyList
\AddToCommaList\MyList{1}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{2}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{3}
\AddToCommaList\MyList{4, 5, 6}
\DumpList[red]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, you might consider merging lists, instead of adding. In that case, you can call the method

```
\skvmergelist{<listcmd>}{<newitems>}
```

or

```
\skvfiltermergelist{<listcmd>}{<newitems>}{<filter>}
```

Comment: Cool... Did not know about the `loops` package. But, yes the list may be defined as macro (I reverted my other answer back for the same reason).

Comment: @PeterGrill: So you might have something like `\AddToCommaList\MyList{\x,\y,3,4}`, where, e.g., `\def\x{1} \def\y{2}`?

Comment: Sure that is more than I had considered.  But,for me it is either _all_ fixed constants passed as a parameter (as in the MWE in the question), or defined something like `\newcommand{\MyListOfValues}{1,2,3,4}`, and then `\AddToCommaSeparateList{\MyList}{MyListOfValues}`. To be able to handle both cases, using an `\edef\Foo` followed by giving `\Foo` _without_ a curly brace group to `\foreach` works (for both cases).

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly.