# Expansion Issue with omit list provided to \DTLdisplaydb

Tags: expansion, datatool

In my DB the number of columns is rather large. Hence, I am trying to eliminate *any* columns which contain only 0 entries.

The number of columns, nor the column keys, are know upfront.
So, I step through the DB and generate a list of columns that are to be omitted.  When I do that the omit list provided seems to be ignored. Below I have omitted the code that determines which columns are

There are no problems for the case of:

- Manually specified omit list: So `\DTLdisplaydb[A,C]{myDB}` works fine.
- Omit list specified by a macro that has fixed content:  So

  ```
  \def\ListOfColumnsToOmit{A,C}
  \DTLdisplaydb[\ListOfColumnsToOmit]{myDB}
  ```

  also works fine.

Only for the case where I compute the list of columns to omit and add them to `\ListOfColumnsToOmit` via the `\AddToCommaSeparateList` macro do things break.

So, the correct result would be that the last table was identical to the two middle tables.

[image]

### References:

- [Expansion issue when adding to CSV list from within a \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83595/expansion-issue-when-adding-to-csv-list-from-within-a-foreach/)
- [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}

% Make csv for question
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyData.csv}
A, B, C, D, E
0, 1, 0, 2, 3
0, 0, 0, 4, 4
0, 2, 0, 0, 5
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83595/expansion-issue-when-adding-to-csv-list-from-within-a-foreach/
\newcommand*{\AddToCommaSeparateList}[3][,\space]{%
    % #1 = separator
    % #2 = listname
    % #3 = content to add to CSV list
    \IfStrEq{#2}{}{}{\g@addto@macro#2{#1}}% Don't add a leading comma in list
    %
    % Extra brace group in case #3 contains a comma
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup%
      \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand#2{{#3}}}\x%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{myDB}{MyData.csv}

With \emph{no} omit list provided:\par
\noindent\DTLdisplaydb{myDB}%

With manually specified omit list:\par
\noindent\DTLdisplaydb[A,C]{myDB}%

\def\ListOfColumnsToOmit{A,C}
With fixed macro  omit list:\par
\noindent\DTLdisplaydb[\ListOfColumnsToOmit]{myDB}%

\def\ListOfColumnsToOmit{}
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\ListOfColumnsToOmit}{A}%
\AddToCommaSeparateList{\ListOfColumnsToOmit}{C}%
With generated macro omit list:\par
\noindent\DTLdisplaydb[\ListOfColumnsToOmit]{myDB}%

The omit list was: \ListOfColumnsToOmit
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, 22 days without an expansion related question from me. Must be a new record. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expansion of `\ListOfColumnsToOmit` in the last case is

```
{A},\space {C}
```

which is obviously wrong. Even omitting the `\space`, which serves no purpose, the additional braces don't allow `datatool` to recognize the column names.

If I use

```
\newcommand*{\AddToCommaSeparateList}[3][,]{%
    % #1 = separator
    % #2 = listname
    % #3 = content to add to CSV list
    \IfStrEq{#2}{}{}{\g@addto@macro#2{#1}}% Don't add a leading comma in list
    %
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand#2{#3}}\x
}
```

then the result is the same as in the "manual" examples.

Comment: Hmmm.. Well it is obviously wrong _only_ in this case - has been working great when I want to typeset the list.. So I guess I'll define in starred variant which does not add the `\space`, and the extra brace group.