# Is there a way to display a specific command and hide the rest

Tags: formatting, conditionals

I would like to use the same Latex source file for both my document and the accompanying slides.

When creating a document it's easy to hide the slide sections by doing this:

```
\newcommand{\slide}[1]{}
```

However, how do I do the inverse, i.e. How can I only generate the slides and hide the rest of the document if I want to print only my slides? Basically I want to say, if the content does not fall in a slide area, then don't show it.

Unfortunately I don't have a simple example to show, because I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: Are you aware of the `Beamer` feature to generate notes and slides in one document? A while ago I created a blog article on this (in German) http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1053

Comment: It seems like, in your situation, you would have to construct the entire document by wrapping things in environments, conditionals, or macros.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll sniff around a bit more. If I come up with a good solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: @JacobusR: Was my solution of any help?

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you @PeterGrill. Just tried it now and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the `environ` package to save the `\BODY` of the document into a `\savebox` which saves the text passed to the `\Slide` macro in a list and output the list at the end.  The following

```
\begin{document}
  abc
  \Slide{Slide 1 content}
  ghi
  \Slide{Slide 2 content}
  jkl
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

### References:

- [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

%% --------------------------
\newsavebox{\DiscardedText}
\newcommand{\Slide}[1]{}
\newcommand{\SavedSlideText}{}
\newcommand\AddToSavedSlideText[1]{\xdef\SavedSlideText{\SavedSlideText#1\endgraf}}
\NewEnviron{GobbleExceptForSlide}{%
    \renewcommand{\Slide}[1]{\AddToSavedSlideText{##1}}%
    \savebox{\DiscardedText}{\BODY}%
    \SavedSlideText%
}%
\AtBeginDocument{\GobbleExceptForSlide}
\AtEndDocument{\endGobbleExceptForSlide}
%% --------------------------



\begin{document}

abc

\Slide{Slide 1 content}

ghi

\Slide{Slide 2 content}


jkl
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried this approach in my documents, but found I get other errors when trying to group my environments. There is a new question in this regard, and I will value your opinion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209258/35071