# Show all colored words at the end of document

Tags: color, keywords

Is there any way to show all colored words at the end of a document?

Say I'm marking definitions as red and theorems as blue.

Is it possible to make a list of "keywords" where all red words is listed, and another list with all blue words.

Something like this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}

    \newcommand{\RC}{\textcolor{red}}
    \newcommand{\BC}{\textcolor{blue}}

\begin{document}
\RC{red1} test

\BC{blue1} test

\BC{blue2} test

\RC{red2} test

    \vfill

\RC{Definitions:}
\begin{itemize}
\item red1
\item red2
\end{itemize}

    \bigskip

\BC{Theorems:}
\begin{itemize}
\item blue1
\item blue2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about using `thmtools`'s `\listoftheorem` macro instead? If you really want colors you can always customize it…

Comment: This might be of help: [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use, for example, this definition of `\RC`, `\BC`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\RC#1{\addto\RClist{\item#1}\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\def\BC#1{\addto\BClist{\item#1}\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\def\RClist{}
\def\BClist{}

\begin{document}
\RC{red1} test

\BC{blue1} test

\BC{blue2} test

\RC{red2} test

    \vfill

\textcolor{red}{Definitions:}
\begin{itemize}
\RClist
\end{itemize}

    \bigskip

\textcolor{blue}{Theorems:}
\begin{itemize}
\BClist
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to make links in \RClist so that when I click on red1 in the list, it will refer to '\RC{red1} test' in the main text?

Comment: I think you might want to use `\gdef` in the definition of `\addto` in case these commands are called from within some kind of scoped group.