# Using csdef in table

Tags: tables, programming, etoolbox

I am trying to automatically add a decision summary when writing meeting minutes. For each paragraph of the meeting I use a table to organize the paragraph number, name and content, and I use etoolbox and csdef to keep track of the decisions following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460175/saving-arguments-of-commands-to-be-used-later) answer. I can not get this to work when using the \motion command within a table. Does anyone know why or how to solve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\enter}{\vskip 3mm}
\newcommand{\decision}[1]{\textbf{The board decided}\\
    \textit{to(1)} #1}
\newcommand{\approve}{approve the motion}

\newcommand{\wrapper}[3]{
    \begin{table}[H]
        {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
            \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} p{4cm} p{10cm}}
                #1 & \raggedright{#2} & \raggedright{#3}\\
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@showMotion}[1]{%
    \showMotion{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\showMotion}[1]{%
    \csuse{name #1} motions to(1)\\\textit{"\csuse{motion #1}"}\enter 
    \decision{\csuse{decision #1}}\enter
}%

\newcommand*{\summary}{% Initialize
}
\newcommand{\addToMotions}[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\summary{{#1}}%
}


\newcommand{\motion}[3]{%
    \ifcsdef{name #1}{%
        \PackageError{\jobname}{Multiple uses of the key: '#1'}{}%
    }{%
        \csdef{name #2}{#1}%
        \csdef{motion #2}{#2}%
        \csdef{decision #2}{#3}%
        \addToMotions{{\@showMotion{#2}}}%
    }%
    #1 motions to(1)\\\textit{"#2"}\enter \decision{#3}\enter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\motion{Test Testersson}{begin testing}{\approve}

\wrapper{§1}{Test}{\motion{Foo bar}{Lorem Ipsum}{\approve}}

\wrapper{§2}{Summary}{\summary{}}

Summary:\\\\

\summary{}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: Resulting document]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  For us non-legal-beagles, what is it precisely you are hoping to have changed?

Comment: Unrelated, raggedright does not take an argument, and cells in a table are already a group.

Comment: Adding `\global` before your `\csdef`s may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I get the gist of what the OP wants; however, it is clear that the `\csdef` invocations, when occurring in a `tabular` cell, will be localized by the scope of the tabular cell.  Thus, making them `\global` gets the information out to other macros that are paying attention.

`\addToMotions` needs no changes, because it already uses `\g@addto@macro`, which is a global assignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\enter}{\vskip 3mm}
\newcommand{\decision}[1]{\textbf{The board decided}\\
    \textit{to(1)} #1}
\newcommand{\approve}{approve the motion}

\newcommand{\wrapper}[3]{
    \begin{table}[H]
        {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
            \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} p{4cm} p{10cm}}
                #1 & \raggedright{#2} & \raggedright{#3}
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@showMotion}[1]{%
    \showMotion{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\showMotion}[1]{%
    \csuse{name #1} motions to(1)\\\textit{"\csuse{motion #1}"}\enter 
    \decision{\csuse{decision #1}}\enter
}%

\newcommand*{\summary}{% Initialize
}
\newcommand{\addToMotions}[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\summary{{#1}}%
}


\newcommand{\motion}[3]{%
    \ifcsdef{name #1}{%
        \PackageError{\jobname}{Multiple uses of the key: '#1'}{}%
    }{%
        \global\csdef{name #2}{#1}%
        \global\csdef{motion #2}{#2}%
        \global\csdef{decision #2}{#3}%
        \addToMotions{{\@showMotion{#2}}}%
    }%
    #1 motions to(1)\\\textit{"#2"}\enter \decision{#3}\enter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\motion{Test Testersson}{begin testing}{\approve}

\wrapper{§1}{Test}{\motion{Foo bar}{Lorem Ipsum}{\approve}}

\wrapper{§2}{Summary}{\summary{}}

Summary:\\

\summary{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The \global before csdef solved it. Thanks!