# Array functionality in TeX?

Tags: tex-core

I've been using LaTeX for a while, but only recently I made myself a mission to create a class. I needed to learn the details of TeX, and I couldn't find answers to some of my questions. One of them is:

**How can I implement a dynamically allocated array in TeX?** One of the environments I defined takes a single parameter such as `{1234}`. I need to split this into characters, which can be done [this way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2711/21372). Then I need to list the numbers such that `array=[1,2,3,4]`.

Then I want to loop the elements of this array and place a single-row tabular environment with `i` columns for each `i` in the array.

To make things clearer, here's is my purpose. One will define a choices environment such that:

```
\begin{choices}{32}
\choice ch1
\choice ch2
\choice ch3
\choice ch4
\choice ch5
\end{choices}
```

is going to create multiple choices in two rows, 3 for the first and 2 for the second (3+2=5):

```
A) ch1  B) ch2  C) ch3
    D) ch4  E) ch5
```

This notation is going to help create more flexible choices, with a maximum number of 9 choices per line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For small-scale arrays, the usual solution is to use a `\csname`-based approach

```
\expandafter\def\csname my@array@1\endcsname{content-for-key-1}
```

which can then be read back just using

```
\csname my@array@1\endcsname
```

Depending on the use case, you may of course want to have the index as a LaTeX counter or TeX count

```
\csname my@array@\the\my@array@index\endcsname
```

Historically, the problem with this approach was that you could run out of space in the hash table for new csnames: TeX used to be 'small' compared with today. Thus the LaTeX3 team have explored storing all of an array using a single name: currently this is how the `prop` data type in `expl3` is implemented.

There is also a question about the performance of TeX's hash algorithm. It's not a particularly efficient one, so collisions are quite common, at least in theory. Thus making the hash table too big might at least in principal impair performance. However, as discussed in [How to implement (low-level) arrays in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147966/how-to-implement-low-level-arrays-in-tex) the practical outcome here is not too bad, so I would not be too concerned about it. The only thing you might want to do is avoid numerical keys.