# Manipulating list items

Tags: lists

**Is there a way to get the n'th element of a list, e.g. an enumerate?** `Itemize`, `enumerate` and others are all wrappers for the `list` environment, defined in the LaTeX kernel.

Regardless of the existence of the n'th element, I want to place the `item`s into a `tabular` environment. The first thing to do would be to prevent the list environment from printing the items. I couldn't exactly grasp the how `list` operates with `\item`, but I would guess calling `\item` does not store the contents of that item in somewhere? And I also guess that what I want to do requires some hooks, since the items are going to be placed arbitrarily in an arbitrary `tabular` environment? Right, I'm a bit confused.

Further explanation: I want to create a multiple choice question environment with a flexible format. Look at [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79437/21372). {32} means 2 tabular environments, one with 3 and the other with 2 columns. I am modifying `choices` environment from the `exam` package.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Guido I edited the question with more explanation.

Comment: Perhaps this might be helpful: [onlyitems? How to select specific items from an item list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/onlyitems-how-to-select-specific-items-from-an-item-list).

Comment: I did a workaround by writing from scratch, but answers are still welcome.

Comment: @OnurSolmaz Why don't you post your workaround here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I wanted to do was to create my own layout to typeset a multiple choice question. Since a multiple choice question is composed of a question body and a list of choices, it was logical to manipulate a Latex list derivative to suit my needs. I did not know my way around TeX Macros at the time, so I did not have a clue on how to do that.

I ended up modifying the environments from the `exam` package. I wanted to place the choices in flexible layouts, so I created two environments `choices` and `choices*`.

`choices` is a simplified version of its counterpart from the `exam` package. I just modified the spaces and choice label. (1 choice per line)

`choices*` allows you to create flexible layouts using the `tabular` environment. For example, if you have 5 choices, you may want to distribute it like 3x2 or 2x2x1, (3 choices for the first line, 2 choices for the second line, and vice versa).

I did it all by **learning** TeX ^^. I mean macros, counters and everything. I asked the question because I did not know how to use arrays, counters and for loops. Now that I know, my question seems irrelevant.

Comment: Ah, I remember when that first happened to me.  The first bit of TeX programming I learned was `\expandafter`.  Then I asked for the TeXbook as a birthday present...