Drawing a tree whose nodes are smaller trees
I want to draw a tree with the following shape, where each boxed tree is a node of a larger tree:

I could find boxing subtrees of a given tree, but all available answers (like this or this) seem to handle smaller trees as subtrees and not nodes. There is one question about including a picture as a node of a tree, which is seemingly helpful to draw my tree with TikZ or forest package. However, I could not figure out how to combine the linked answer to draw my tree with tikz or forest.
Add: Here is a code scratch I used. I want to add sub-trees (as nodes) in place of question marks.
\tikzset{
  solid/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
  itria/.style={draw, isosceles triangle, shape border rotate=90,yshift=-1.45em},
  solidstar/.style={star,star points=5,star point ratio=0.4,draw,inner sep=2.8,rotate=180,fill=black},
  hollowstar/.style={star,star points=5,star point ratio=0.4,draw,inner sep=2.8,rotate=180},
}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        [[,solid[?1
            [,solid[?3
                [,solid[?4
                    [,solid[?6]]
                    ]
                ]
                [,solid[?5
                    [,solid[?7]]]]
                    ]
                ] 
            [,solid[?8
                [,solid[?9]]]]
            ]
            ]
        [,solid[?2]]]
    \end{forest}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

% Node 1
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{1em}
% Node 2
\begin{forest}
    [[,solidstar]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{1em}
% Node 3
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{1em}
% Node 4
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar][,hollow]]]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{1em}
\hspace{1em}
% Node 5
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar]]][,hollow]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{1em}
% Node 6
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar][,solid]]][,hollow]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{1em}
% Node 7
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar]]][,hollow[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{1em}
% Node 8
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid][,hollowstar]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{1em}
% Node 9
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]][,solidstar]]
\end{forest}


Just to be clear: you specifically don't want the sub trees to be connected to the main tree, i.e., it's not sufficient to simply box a node, but instead the boxes themselves are the nodes, whose content is a subtree.  Do I understand this correctly?

Perhaps In a tree, how do you have a node that is a also a tree? would do what you want?

@AlanMunn Yes, correct. The boxes should be nodes of a tree.

can you provide the code for the separate trees?

is there a pattern? are those empty set symbols?

@cfr Empty set is a symbol, and all others are nodes. I could provide some command set for the nodes I used, but every attempt to build an actual tree returned an error and I removed codes after the error, meaning that I do not have actual code on my hand.

@HanulJeon I just want something to copy-paste so I don't have to keep switching desktops to code the tree's structure. if you have something like forest code for the individual nodes and/or the overall tree (with, say, just A, B, C where the smaller trees should be) that would be helpful. and then I don't have to guess symbols, either.

@cfr Then let me try to build a tree without smaller tree nodes. You may use any smaller tree nodes as you want. (I can include some sample smaller tree codes when it is necessary.)

@cfr I coded the full code that you may need. I hope this helps.

@AlanMunn could you explain the distinction you were making above between boxing nodes and nodes being boxes? every node in a forest tree is a box already ...

you can definitely get this to work manually as @AlanMunn did, but it has to be possible to do better than that if you are better with TeX boxes than me. I guess I might be forced to turn to knuth ....

I came up with the following "semi-manual" code by combining Alan Munn's answer with \loop:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  solid/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
  itria/.style={draw, isosceles triangle, shape border rotate=90,yshift=-1.45em},
  solidstar/.style={star,star points=5,star point ratio=0.4,draw,inner sep=2.8,rotate=180,fill=black},
  hollowstar/.style={star,star points=5,star point ratio=0.4,draw,inner sep=2.8,rotate=180},
}

% Defining boxes I will use
\newcounter{myctr}
\loop
    \stepcounter{myctr}
    \expandafter\newsavebox\csname ChVInodebox\Alph{myctr}\endcsname
\ifnum\value{myctr}<10 \repeat

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxA}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,hollow]]
\end{forest}
}

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxB}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,hollowstar]]
\end{forest}
}

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxC}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]]]
\end{forest}
}

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxD}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar][,hollow]]]]
\end{forest}
}

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxE}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar]]][,hollow]]
\end{forest}
}

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxF}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar][,solid]]][,hollow]]
\end{forest}
}

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxG}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar]]][,solid[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]]]
\end{forest}
}

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxH}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,solid][,hollowstar]]
\end{forest}
}

\savebox{\ChVInodeboxI}{
\begin{forest} for tree={fit=tight, for children={l sep-=1em,l-=1em}}
    [[,solid[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]][,solidstar]]
\end{forest}
}

% Main tree
\begin{forest}
    [[,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxA}}
        [,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxC}}
            [,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxD}}
                [,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxF}}]]
                ]
            ]
            [,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxE}}
                [,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxG}}]]]]
                ]
            ] 
        [,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxH}}
            [,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxI}}]]]]
        ]
        ]
    [,solid[\fbox{\usebox{\ChVInodeboxB}}]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

It gives the following image:

(Sorry, I changed the first two 'sub-tree' nodes since it is what I wanted. I changed filled node trees into hollow node trees.)
It will be better if there is a more elegant method: I do not like introducing a bunch of new box commands just for a single illustration. Also, the current box naming scheme uses alphabets, which is sometimes confusing. But I have no idea if there is a way to use Arabic numbers to name boxes.

Make your code compilable. Please...

Unfortunately your posted tree can't compile: please complete your code. // Digits have the wrong catcode, which, AFAIK, is the reason why you can't have macros with digits. However, instead of looping you can also spell out that code (10 times) and use other postfixes than A, B, C ..., or use a lookup mechanism via the counters value.

@projetmbc Now it should be compilable.

@MS-SPO Could you clarify what you mean for a lookup mechanism? I do not want to spell a similar code 10 times as the repetition may be indefinitely long for a more complicated tree.

In other programming languages you could use arrays, to assign different postfixes to integer indices (integer-lookup). Or hashes, which use key-value pairs (which is similar, i.e. not bound to integer "keys"; key-lookup). TeX/LaTeX's on-board feature is shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79438/245790 . You can also use key-value packages, like pgfkeys. And, if I remember correctly, both arrays and hashes are available in L3.

Elaboarting said link a little you could define and fill my array (marr)`\def\marr#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname my@array@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\rarr#1{\csname my@array@#1\endcsname}
\marr{33}{hallo}
\marr{-1}{moin}and try reading or recalling (if existent) lie\rarr{33}` (read array).

@MS-SPO that's all true, but the involvement of forest changes things a bit. on the one hand, it isn't straightforward to integrate that kind of code directly (so you could still generate boxes, but then you don't avoid the boxes, of course). on the other, forest expands pgfkeys very substantially - not just in terms of available keys, but in terms of available key types and key handlers. so you have interfaces for handling arrays (at least, if the \def... stuff counts as an array, I guess something like a nodewalk or a keylist does? and certainly counters etc.

I think there must be a better way of doing this, but it requires more expertise with TeX boxes and grouping than I possess.
This is not quite right, but perhaps somebody can see where my calculation is wrong. (I've left some typeout lines commented, if anybody would be interested in looking.)
This requires two things in terms of markup.

An additional root node. Basically, surround the whole tree by another set of square brackets. Alternatively, you could make a specialist environment for trees of this kind, in which case you could dispense with the additional brackets.
Passing the nested trees to their nodes via an option, nest. The contents of the nested trees must be braced i.e. surrounded by curly brackets.
Adding nested trees to the preamble.

The result definitely need some attention in terms of formatting. I added some width, but it would probably be better to alter the definitions of the node styles to use less minute inner sep.

The basic strategy is to append the nested trees to the invisible root, calculate their dimensions, set the node text height and width to the appropriate values and then move the nested trees to the correct positions just before drawing the tree. (prooftrees uses a similar idea to position line numbers and justifications.)
What I don't understand is either the text height or the locations from which the edges are drawn to the children of nested trees when there are two rather than one.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  solid/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
  solidstar/.style={star,star points=5,star point ratio=0.4,draw,inner sep=2.8,rotate=180,fill=black},
  hollowstar/.style={star,star points=5,star point ratio=0.4,draw,inner sep=2.8,rotate=180},
}
\makeatletter
\forestset{% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726532/
  declare boolean={nested}{0},
  declare boolean={protected}{1},
  declare count register={nests},
  nests'=0,
  declare count={nest site}{0},
  declare count={nest no}{0},
  declare toks={nest content}{},
  declare keylist register={nest sites},
  nest sites={},
  declare dimen={nest l}{0pt},
  declare dimen={nest s}{0pt},
  nest/.style={%
    nests'+=1,
    nest content={#1},
    nest no/.register=nests,
    nested,
    nest sites+/.register=nests,
    name/.process={Rw{nests}{nest site ##1}},
    before packing={%
      delay={
        typeset node,
      },
    },
  },
  protect nest/.style={%
    !r.append/.option=!{name=nest site #1}.nest content,
    do dynamics,
    where={>OOn=On=&&{protected}{level}{1}{nest site}{0}}{%
      nest site=#1,
      before packing={%
        pack,
        for leaves={%
          tempdima'=0pt,
          tempdimb'=0pt,
          for current and ancestors={%
            tempdima+/.option=l,
            if={>Od<{s}{0pt}}{%
              tempdimb-/.option=s,
            }{%
              tempdimb+/.option=s,
            },
          },
          tempdima-/.option=!r.l,
          % tempdimb-/.option=!r.s,
          nest l/.register=tempdima,
          nest s/.register=tempdimb,
        },
        tempdimc/.max={>O{nest l}}{leaves},
        % tempdimc/.max={>OOOw3+d{nest l}{max y}{min y}{##1+##2-##3}}{leaves},
        tempdimd/.max={>OOOw3+d{nest s}{max x}{min x}{##1+##2-##3}}{leaves},
        tempdimd'+=5pt,
        tempdimc'+=5pt,
        !{name=nest site #1}.draw,
        !{name=nest site #1}.text width/.register=tempdimd,
        !{name=nest site #1}.text height/.register=tempdimc,
      },
      before drawing tree={%
        % typeout/.option=y,
        % typeout/.option=!{name=nest site #1}.y,
        % typeout/.option=!{name=nest site #1}.min y,
        % typeout/.option=!{name=nest site #1}.max y,
        tempdima/.option=!{name=nest site #1}.x,
        tempdima-/.option=x,
        tempdimb/.option=!{name=nest site #1}.y,
        tempdimb-/.option=y,
        tempdimb+/.option=!{name=nest site #1}.max y,
        tempdimb+/.option=!{name=nest site #1}.min y,
        for tree={%
          x+/.register=tempdima,
          y+/.register=tempdimb,
        },
      },
    }{},
  },
  nested trees/.style={%
    coordinate,
    phantom,
    before computing xy={%
      for children={l'=0pt},
    },
    for tree={not protected},
    delay={%
      delay={%
        split register={nest sites}{,}{protect nest},
      },
    },
  },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  nested trees,
  % cwestiwn Hanul Jeon: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726499/
  [
    [
      [,solid
        [, nest={[[,solid]]}
          [,solid
            [,nest={[[,solid[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]]]}
              [,solid
                [,nest={[[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar][,hollow]]]]}
                  [,solid
                    [,nest={[[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar][,solid]]][,hollow]]}]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [,solid
                [,nest={[[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar]]][,hollow]]}
                  [,solid
                    [,nest={[[,solid[$\emptyset$[,solidstar]]][,hollow[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]]]}]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
          [,solid
            [,nest={[[,solid][,hollowstar]]}
              [,solid
                [,nest={[[,solid[$\emptyset$[,hollowstar]]][,solidstar]]}]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [,solid
        [,nest={[[,solidstar]]}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

