# Vertical "stack" of letters, where every letter is rotated to sit on top of the letter beneath it

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a simple method in tikz, where I can rotate text so that each letter in the text "sits" or is "stacked" on top of the successor letter. For example, the word "Environment" would appear as:

```
E
n
v
i
r
o
n
m
e
n
t
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.

Comment: Welcome Tom!  Your question might already have an answer at the link in my comment above.  Add a comment if you disagree.

Comment: I kind of disagree, that question does not say how to put an arbitrary string vertically (other than putting manual linebreaks). There might be another duplicate somewhere though.

Comment: @Marijn:  True, but the OP doesn't say that manual linebreaks are not allowed either.  Looks like we're getting some good non-Tikz answers below anyway.

Comment: See the `stackengine` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Answer (score 6):

Usually I start answers with "If you do not mind loading Ti*k*Z, you could ..." but here one may say: If you do not mind not using Ti*k*Z you could use `soul` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@soeverytoken{%
 {\the\SOUL@token}\par\noindent}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent\so{Environment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This answer is inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2709). If someone wants to downvote me (again) for quoting others, go ahead.

The Ti*k*Z library `decorations.text` offers advanced options such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={text effects along path, 
text={Environment},
text effects/.cd,
path from text angle=-90,
path from text,
characters={text along path},
character widths={inner xsep=1pt},
style characters=mw with {blue,inner xsep=0.4pt},
style characters=bdfhjklt with {red,inner xsep=1.5pt},
style characters=i with {orange,inner xsep=2.2pt},
style characters=gpqy with {inner xsep=1.2pt}}]
\path [ decorate,
text effects={characters/.append={/utils/exec=\pgftransformresetnontranslations}}] (1,0); \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `\pgftransformresetnontranslations` is used to "unrotated" the characters.

And since there seems to be a desire to employ as little packages as possible: you don't need any.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\endpft{Yekitiyekitipeng}%<- something crazy
\def\rst{}
\def\pft#1#2\endpft{\ifx#2\endpft%
\else%
#1\\%
\def\rst{#2}
\pft#2\endpft%
\fi}
\newcommand{\vtext}[2][]{\begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.63}%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}%
\,\pft#2\endpft\rst%
\end{tabular}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\vtext{Environment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether or not it is worthwhile to have as little packages as possible is a different question. IMHO this is only the case if you get the same result with less packages. On the other hand, Ti*k*Z allows you to easily typeset the text along a curve, something that is hard to achieve without packages.

Comment: `style characters=gpqy` as far as I can see, none of these are actually part of the word “Environment”.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes. This is meant to work for other words, too. The reason why I did that is that by default Ti*k*Z would space the characters according to their width, but after adding `\pgftransformresetnontranslations` the relevant dimension is the height. So these `style characters` also serve the purpose of "fixing" the spacing. (There are alternative ways such as `rotate` but as far as I can see none of them will work for arbitrary curves in the way `\pgftransformresetnontranslations` does.)

Answer (score 5):

No Ti*k*Z, sorry.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\stack}{O{c}m}
 {
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}
  \tl_map_function:nN { #2 } \__tom_stack:n
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__tom_stack:n { #1 \\ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

x\stack{Environment}\qquad x\stack[t]{Environment}\qquad x\stack[b]{Environment}

\end{document}
```

We simply map the argument to populate a `tabular`. The optional argument sets the reference point just like for `tabular` (the `x` in the examples shows the reference point).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With MetaFun

```
\startMPpage
string s ;
s := "Experiment" ;
for i = 1 upto length s:
    label(substring (i - 1, i) of s, (0,-i*.5cm)) ;
endfor ;
\stopMPpage
```

[image]

Comment: Just realized that in the original post it says “Environment”, not “Experiment”.  Well... that is an exercise left to the reader.