# Single character vertical alignment options

Tags: vertical-alignment

How to break single character as vertical align as shown in the images?[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507786).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is very closely related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507786), so I borrow the main code from there. And use it to build something reminiscent to your table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\def\endpft{Yekitiyekitipeng}%<- something crazy
\def\rst{}
\def\pft#1#2\endpft{\ifx#2\endpft%
\else%
#1\\%
\def\rst{#2}
\pft#2\endpft%
\fi}
\newcommand{\vtext}[2][]{\begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.67}%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}%
\,\pft#2\endpft\rst%
\end{tabular}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\begin{tabular}{|*3{p{8em}|}C{7em}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Increasing risk} & \multirow{2}{*}{\vtext{risk}~
 \vtext{~Increasing}} \\[3.5em]
\cline{1-3}
 & Current products & New products &  \\[3.5em]
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]