# Print binary number with spacing

Tags: formatting

I've been trying to print a binary number with a small space, automatically, every four digits. Starting from right and moving to the left.

I found [this](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/numprint/nbaseprt.pdf) package that allowed me to achieve this, but unfortunately, it requires me to add a

```
0b
```

in front of each number. I'd rather not print out this at all, as I use a

```
$_2$
```

Can someone help me use this package and **not** print out

```
0b
```

or a different way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: I found in a related question the package [siunitx](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf), it seems that there is an option called `group-four-digits` that solves what you need, maybe you should check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably other ways, but this one (inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2709)) seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcounter{binst}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\FormatBinary}[1]{\begingroup%
\setcounter{binst}{0}
\def\SOUL@soeverytoken{%
\stepcounter{binst}%
\ifnum\value{binst}=5\relax%
\setcounter{binst}{1}\,%
\fi%
\the\SOUL@token}%
\so{#1}\endgroup} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\FormatBinary{100100010010}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, this works perfectly! Thank you so much! After I'm done making my document, I'm going to go through this and ask some followup questions so I can understand why this works. Thank you!

Comment: For a number like 11110, it will format it as "1111 0" instead of "1 1110", is there a way to fix this? I see the `soeveryoken`, is there a way to do this but backwards?