# Using soul as tokenizer gives strange result on specific strings

Tags: soul

Following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/how-to-split-text-into-characters#2709), I was trying to use `soul` as a hack-y tokenizer and ran into unexpected behavior on certain strings. I reduced the problem to the following MWE but haven't been able to make further progress:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

% Initially empty, then should be nonempty afterward
\newcommand*{\state}{}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@soeverytoken{%
  \ifx\state\empty%  Should only happen once...
    \renewcommand*{\state}{Nonempty}%
    (\the\SOUL@token)%
  \else%
    [\the\SOUL@token]%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  % For some reason, the string "unrnn" gives an unexpected result.
  \so{nnrnn} \par % (n)[n][r][n][n]
  \so{unrnn} \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
  \so{unnnn} \par % (u)[n][n][n][n]
  \so{unrn}  \par % (u)[n][r][n]
\end{document}
```

On the string `unrnn`, it prints out `(r)` rather than `[r]` as I would expect. From printing out `\state`, it seems like it's becoming nonempty after reading the `r`, but I'm not sure why this doesn't occur in the other examples.

Comment: May I ask why you are using `soul` for this when the LaTeX kernel these days have tools to go through token lists etc.

Comment: No principled reason. I'm fairly new to LaTeX macro programming and followed the top suggestion in the post linked above. I'll take a closer look at the kernel tools---thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but when the string `unrnn` is examined, TeX is at grouping level 3; however, when `r` is being processed, the grouping level decreases to 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

% Initially empty, then should be nonempty afterward
\newcommand*{\state}{}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@soeverytoken{%
\showthe\currentgrouplevel
\show\state
\showthe\SOUL@token
  \ifx\state\empty%  Should only happen once...
    \renewcommand*{\state}{Nonempty}%
    (\the\SOUL@token)%
  \else
    [\the\SOUL@token]%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  % For some reason, the string "unrnn" gives an unexpected result.
%  \so{nnrnn} \par % (n)[n][r][n][n]
  \so{unrnn} \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
%  \so{unnnn} \par % (u)[n][n][n][n]
%  \so{unrn}  \par % (u)[n][r][n]
\end{document}
```

I added some diagnostic commands to see what happens.

```
> 3.
\SOUL@everytoken ->\showthe \currentgrouplevel
                                               \show \state \showthe \SOUL@t...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> \state=macro:
->.
\SOUL@everytoken ...urrentgrouplevel \show \state
                                                  \showthe \SOUL@token \ifx ...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> u.
\SOUL@everytoken ...w \state \showthe \SOUL@token
                                                  \ifx \state \empty \renewc...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> 3.
\SOUL@everytoken ->\showthe \currentgrouplevel
                                               \show \state \showthe \SOUL@t...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> \state=macro:
->Nonempty.
\SOUL@everytoken ...urrentgrouplevel \show \state
                                                  \showthe \SOUL@token \ifx ...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> n.
\SOUL@everytoken ...w \state \showthe \SOUL@token
                                                  \ifx \state \empty \renewc...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> 2.
\SOUL@everytoken ->\showthe \currentgrouplevel
                                               \show \state \showthe \SOUL@t...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> \state=macro:
->.
\SOUL@everytoken ...urrentgrouplevel \show \state
                                                  \showthe \SOUL@token \ifx ...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> r.
\SOUL@everytoken ...w \state \showthe \SOUL@token
                                                  \ifx \state \empty \renewc...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
> 2.
\SOUL@everytoken ->\showthe \currentgrouplevel
                                               \show \state \showthe \SOUL@t...
l.24   \so{unrnn}
                  \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
?
```

If I try with `\so{nnrnn}` the grouping level starts from 2.

I'd avoid overloading `\so`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myso}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \gdef\my@state{}%
  \def\SOUL@soeverytoken{%
    \ifx\my@state\empty%  Should only happen once...
      \gdef\my@state{x}%
      (\the\SOUL@token)%
    \else
      [\the\SOUL@token]%
    \fi
  }%
  \so{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myso{nnrnn} \par % (n)[n][r][n][n]
\myso{unrnn} \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
\myso{unnnn} \par % (u)[n][n][n][n]
\myso{unrn}  \par % (u)[n][r][n]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with `expl3` and `\text_map_inline:nn`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myso}{m}
 {
  \airwreck_process:n { #1 }
 }

\bool_new:N \l_airwreck_first_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \airwreck_process:n
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_airwreck_first_bool
  \text_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_airwreck_first_bool
     {% first item
      (##1)
      \bool_set_false:N \l_airwreck_first_bool
     }
     {% other items
      [##1]
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myso{nnrnn} \par % (n)[n][r][n][n]
\myso{unrnn} \par % (u)[n](r)[n][n]
\myso{unnnn} \par % (u)[n][n][n][n]
\myso{unrn}  \par % (u)[n][r][n]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions---I will probably go with the `expl3` implementation.

Answer (score 5):

As background: soul analyses syllables, to allow for hyphenation. So the result of parsing can depend on the language: In german `unt` is a syllable and so the parser restarts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{soul}

% Initially empty, then should be nonempty afterward
\newcommand*{\state}{}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@soeverytoken{%
  \ifx\state\empty%  Should only happen once...
    \renewcommand*{\state}{Nonempty}%
    (\the\SOUL@token)%
  \else%
    [\the\SOUL@token]%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \so{untnn} \par %
  
  \selectlanguage{ngerman}
  
  \so{untnn} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, this makes sense as an explanation for the different behavior on different strings. Thanks for the insight!